# VisualStudio: translating a build version to a calendar date

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, versioning

I know that the version string generated by Visual Studio is based on the date/time of when the build was run. Given the partial version string "3856.24352" generated by Visual Studio, how can I translate that to the calendar day on which that build took place?

Comment: The current .NET 4.0 version is v4.0.30319.  Make sense, if you know the secret key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The full version string is in the format **major.minor.build.revision**. The **build** part is the number of days since 1<sup>st</sup> January, 2000. The **revision** part is the number of seconds since midnight divided by 2 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k49w9389(v=VS.100).aspx) for more info).

Assuming that your version strings are the auto-incrementing type, and that you have taken the **build.revision** part, you can turn it back into the date using:

```
string buildRevision = "3856.24352";

string[] parts = buildRevision.Split('.');
int build = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int revision = int.Parse(parts[1]);

DateTime dateTimeOfBuild = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) 
                                + new TimeSpan(build, 0, 0, 0) 
                                + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(revision * 2);
```

This will give you a `DateTime` representing when the build was produced (which for your example is 23<sup>rd</sup> July, 2010 at 13:31:44).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple javascript tool for converting .Net version into a date:

**Sample Input:**
1.0.7769.27451

**Sample Output:**
5/9/2021, 3:15:02 PM

```js
function convertBuildNumberToDate()
{
  var buildString = document.getElementById("input").value.split(".");
  var buildNumber = Number(buildString[2]);
  var revision = Number(buildString[3]);

  var date = new Date(2000, 1, 1);
  date.setDate(buildNumber);
  date.setSeconds(revision * 2);

  var output = date.toLocaleString();
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
Build Number:
<br />
<input id="input" value="1.0.7769.27451" />
<button onclick="convertBuildNumberToDate()">Convert</button>

<br />
<br />

Build Date:
<br />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I build my application today (2021-12-06) and realesed the version is 1.0.8010.28393. Then i converted this version to date, it gives the 2022-01-05. I couldn't get it what is wrong?

Comment: Indeed, the date is about one month ahead of what it should be, although the time seems correct. I can't see where the bug is, though. Even the example in the answer is wrong - 7769 should give 9 April 2021.