# How do I make automatic version numbers work in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been asked to add automatic numbering to assemblies in our code library. I've been changing versions from the default 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.* like this:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

It generates a number as I'd like.

However, the code library has many hundreds of DLLs, with many referencing each other. Now when I compile some projects they complain that the version of a DLL needed by a referenced component is not correct and they won't build :(

How can I make this work? We need it so that when a DLL at the bottom of our code library hierarchy is compiled, all other DLLs that reference it work correctly without needing recompiling.

The error I get is like this:

```
Error   1   CA0058 : The referenced assembly 'Library1, Version=1.0.4146.17993
, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9c65edd2096ad48' could not be found. This assembly
is required for analysis and was referenced by:
D:\Work\Source Code\Library\Library2\bin\Release\Library2.dll.
```

The version 1.0.4146.17993 is not correct - the DLL has a higher value. The DLLs are set to Copy Local because the software we deliver requires it (don't ask why). The DLL that's copied locally is the one with the higher version number, which is the one we want it to be.

So far I've tried changing the references to set the "Specific Version" flag to false but this didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The version numbers that VS generates when you use the `1.0.*` syntax are not necessarily going to increment in *sequence*. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) has this to say (emphasis added):

> You can specify all the values or you can accept the default build number, revision number, or both by using an asterisk (*). For example, [assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")] indicates 2 as the major version, 3 as the minor version, 25 as the build number, and 1 as the revision number. A version number such as [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")] specifies 1 as the major version, 2 as the minor version, and accepts the default build and revision numbers. A version number such as [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")] specifies 1 as the major version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts the default revision number. **The default build number increments daily. The default revision number is random.**

If it's vital that you get versioning exactly right, I highly recommend that you use a third-party solution. The [Build Version Increment](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/) add-in is excellent.

What you want to do is manage the assembly version yourself. Only increment this when you make a breaking change to the assembly's public interface. Changing this attribute makes your assembly incompatible with other assemblies that reference it, even if you didn't change a thing in your code. Instead, the only thing you want to automatically increment is the assembly *file* version. Unlike the assembly version, this attribute is not checked by the CLR to determine compatibility.

The Build Version Increment add-in gives you the kind of fine-grained control over what is incremented that you need to get this right. It's what probably should be included in VS to begin with.

Comment: We aren't worried about the versions being in sequence as long as the overall version increases (which the Visual Studio system does as its based upon date and time). Even with a manual increment or an alternative solution I think we'd have the same problem.

Comment: @Richard: Make sure you refresh the page to see my last edits. If you alter the `[AssemblyVersion]` attribute, you'll be indicating to the CLR that the assembly is now incompatible with previous versions. You need to increment the `[AssemblyFileVersion]` attribute instead. Visual Studio doesn't get this right, but a 3rd-party tool gives you more control over which one gets incremented.

Comment: In the end I went back to fixed assembly versions and manually updating file versions. Would be interested in any recommendation you have for a tool to do this automatically on building.

Comment: @Richard: Have you tried [Build Version Increment](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/)? I've used it to do exactly that.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately it sometimes seems to not bother doing updates. Do you know of any other software?

Comment: @Richard: In my experience, it won't update the version number if that particular assembly is not rebuilt. If your solution has multiple projects (each of which compile to separate assemblies), Visual Studio will not re-compile those to which you haven't made any changes, at least by default. You can change that by flipping a switch in the Options dialog. I'd start there first; it's unlikely to be a bug in the add-in. I've never seen this reported by anyone else, nor have I experienced it myself. But the minimal rebuild, though designed for convenience, often trips people up.

Comment: Since .Net 4.5, revision number is not random, but calculated > The default revision number is the number of seconds since midnight local time (without taking into account time zone adjustments for daylight saving time), divided by 2

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a pretty indepth question, and I hope someone answers this in detail for you, but my 2 cents after you get the assembly infos under control is you should look at using `Nuget` to manage your dependencies. This way when team A releases v2 of assembly X, all they do is put it on your Nuget repo (network share probably) and then you can basically right click < update inside your projects that consume the DLLs.

I would also recommend looking at http://semver.org/ and use Semantic Versioning, if you don't want to follow a system like this one (or institute a similar standard for your shop), it's probably not worth even trying to version your DLLs you're just going to give yourself massive headaches. However using Semantic Versioning will make your version numbers actually MEAN something. And not just be whatever felt like being tagged onto the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Revision number is not random. It is the time of day of the build. The Build is the day number.

See [VisualStudio: translating a build version to a calendar date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982953/visualstudio-translating-a-build-version-to-a-calendar-date)

Answer (score 0):

delete your reference (in the project that uses it) and re-do it by pointing to the project reference type.

**PS: If when you are adding the reference, you choose browse and point to a place the dll will always be, the reference will not be broken!**

Comment: There isn't one in the GAC. These are all DLLs held in a library folder.

Comment: @Richard for the most part this is the flat answer on fixing the build error, many times you will get a FILE reference to a dll inside of the bin folder of an alternate project instead of a true project reference. Generally just removing the reference and using the add project reference through the dialogs will fix it.

Comment: I think the problem is that the projects aren't rebuilt. So when project A references library A and library B, and library B references library A as well, the true version of library A is not necessarily the one that library B knows about. so removing and replacing the reference doesn't work. Rebuilding everything probably would but that takes hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
   > However, the code library has many hundreds of DLLs,
```

If it is ok for you that all source projects and their generated dll-s have the same version-number you can put the versionnumber into one file that is shared between all dlls as described in 
[shared AssemblyInfo.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759644/updating-the-version-number-of-all-assemblies-in-a-solution/759659#759659). So you (or the version-number-generator you are using) have to update only one file if there is a new relase/Version.

This does not answer your original question but may be a simple workaroud for the dependency problem.